# Why doesn't my fluid simulation look realistic?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I created a fluid simulation for nearly one week.
A soda can that pours water into an invisible glass.
But the water does not look realistic.
Why is this?

Settings:

- Resolution Divisions: 128
- Mesh: Upres Factor: 2

(I'm not sure which settings are important, so I put it in the image)

By the way, is this normal?
The first frame takes some seconds to render, but starting around frame 80 it takes longer and longer.
Frame 180, for example, takes nearly 30 minutes to render.

My render needs over one day to finish and the result looks so bad.

Blender file: [image]

[image: render settings]

Comment: Well, without knowing your hardware specifications, this is just a general statement, but yes - it is (or can be) normal that it takes longer from frame to frame. I suppose you're using a flow object set to _Inflow_, which means the longer the simulation runs, the more and more particles are there and the more complex the simulation becomes. You've also enabled foam and bubbles which makes it's even worse.

Comment: And how should the liquid look realistic? Which liquid glows from the inside (_Emission_ shader?) Another thing is, depending on what kind of liquid this is supposed to be, the _Volume Absorption_ doesn't do much if set to white, it only makes it darker but maybe not with this low density. What I would suggest is get rid of the _Emission_ shader, set the _Glass BSDF_ to white or just slightly tinted in the desired color, set the color you want for the liquid in the _Volume Absorption_ and maybe increase the density. Also check _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ > _Volume_, set it higher than 0.

Comment: I would also suggest you to check the scale of your models. To have realistic simulations you need to use real-life scale. I said that, tho, because I can't really guess what you mean by "does not look realistic", is it the shading, the physics, both or the bubbles?

Comment: Or for the liquid material, even better than using the _Volume Absorption_ it would be to take a _Principled Volume_ shader. Set the color you want as _Color_ and play with the _Anisotropy_ value for different results. You could also set an _Absorption Color_ in the node.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12 Core / NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 / Samsung SSD 970 SCSI / 32GB DDR4

It should be a soda. With bubbles and so on. Like this (that's the original one) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypnyeghnxx7559j/Soda_real.jpg?dl=0 The first is another flavor

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka my can is 2x2x4,84 m but this is the Blender scale... The liquid looks not realistic enough for me. It looks a bit thick. Also the bubbles and splash look wrong.

Comment: I think that's too big. Your water looks thick because it IS thick as expected from a stream of water flowing from a 2x2x4.8 m^3 can!

Comment: The average coke can is around 6cmx6cmx12cm. If you want your animation to be realistic, you should begin with that. When it comes to physics simulations, you always need to use real world scale. If you use that big of a can, your water's gonna look like it's flowing in slowmotion and I don't think you want that.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I started a new project with smaller scale but my glass was not able to hold the water. It flowed 
out.

Comment: I mean, of course it will flow out if the liquid is too much to be contained by the glass. But you can make it smaller, can't you?

Answer (score 5):

I needed some time to just learn from the Blender default settings instead of watching hours for hours bad tutorials.

So just do this:

Create a cube. Objects -> Quick effects -> quick liquid. Then just check the "mesh" box in domain settings.

If you just run the simulation in material preview you will get:

[image]

And this is "only" a resolution of 32!!

And in my opinion it looks already great.

If you then check the material Blender gifted us:

[image]

That's pretty basic and looks already awesome.

Then you should play around with settings and tweak some settings.

Checking "diffusion" will make some more splashes:

[image]

Increase resolution in water simulations is always a good idea. But yes, it will take machine power and your time.

From left to right:

Resolution 32, 32 + diffusion, 64, 128

[image]

If you want "detail" explanation why yours doesn't look realistic, please provide blend file so we can check it out. It depends not only on domain settings, but on shader, inflow and light settings as well. And for water simulations in 99% of all cases Cycles will do a much better job than EEVEE. I my examples here are just EEVEE....

Cycles:

[image]

Another hint (no, unfortunately i don't get any money from them - not even just a cup of coffee): Flip Fluids is a great add-on which makes fluid simulations not only look better but even quicker and easier to use. Yes, you have to pay for it but i never regret buying it. And it has e.g. inbuild materials for different fluids.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Yes, I spent hours in YT to understand how it works and yes, my tutorial one looks good but my own one was this...so I want to understand what's wrong.  I added the file

Comment: please do file -> external data -> pack resources , save blender file and upload again so that i can see something. Thank you!

Comment: The file is bigger than 30MB so I upladet it on Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5m4hqh0462yx1t/Dose_v3.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hi Sven, i don't know why, but whenever i bake your simulation Blender crashes. This happens for 3.1 and 3.2. So i give up now...sorry.